# How can I set the contents of an array inside an object to false if it is null?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following to get some data and load it into an object:

```
test.qs = data;
```

The object qs then looks something like this:

```
[
 {"answer":null,
  "answered":true,
  // many more fields here
  "answers":{"correct":null,"response":null}},
 {"answer":null,
  "answered":true,
  // many more fields here
  "answers":{"correct":null,"response":null}}
]
```

How can I make it so that if the response value in the array is null then it is changed to false?

Comment: Why would you want to change `null` to `false`? They don't convey the same information. I smell trouble... I'd rather fix the code that generates the data, if you really want `false`.

Comment: It's populating a check box which would have a value of false if it has not yet been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x=[
 {"answer":null,
  "answered":true,
  // many more fields here
  "answers":{"correct":null,"response":null}},
 {"answer":null,
  "answered":true,
  // many more fields here
  "answers":{"correct":null,"response":null}}
];
var string=JSON.stringify(x).toString().replace(/\:null/g, ":false");
var json=jQuery.parseJSON(string);
```

This will change all null's into false

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(test.qs).each(function () {
  $(this).each(function (i) {
    for(var props in this) {
      if(test.qs[i][props] == null)
        test.qs[i][props] = false;
    }
  });
});
```

**Note:**

You need jQuery to perform this code + depending on where you are pasing the code, it should be available globally, so if the code doesn't work add next one where your variable is declared:

```
window.test = test;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it: You want to change the value of "response" to false if it has the value "null". Assuming that each object in your Array has the same structure, than this should work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < test.qs.length; ++i)
{
    if(test.qs[i]["answers"]["response"] == null)
    {
        test.qs[i]["answers"]["response"] = false;
    }
}
```